# FTX API in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch

i keep getting this error

> Exception: Request failed for https://ftx.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"success":false,"error":"Not logged in"}
> (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)"

What is wrong with my code?

```
var host = 'https://ftx.com';
var endpoint ='/api/wallet/all_balances';
var url = host + endpoint;

var timestamp = ''+ new Date().getTime();
var payload = timestamp + 'GET' + endpoint+'';

var shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-256", "BYTES");
shaObj.setHMACKey(api_secret, "BYTES");
shaObj.update(payload);
var signature = shaObj.getHMAC("HEX");

var options = {
 method: 'get',
 headers: {
  'FTX-KEY': api_key,
  'FTX-TS': timestamp,
  'FTX-SIGN': signature
  },
 muteHTTPExceptions: 'true'
}

var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var data   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());
```

Comment: I have never known the API you want to use. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So, in order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the official document of the API you want to use?

Comment: Here is the official Api    https://docs.ftx.com/#overview

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? In my test, I confirmed that the request of the python script of the official document is the same as the converted Google Apps Script. So, if an error occurs, please check your `api_key` and `secret` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to request the [Get balances of all accounts](https://docs.ftx.com/#get-balances-of-all-accounts) of FTX API using Google Apps Script.
- The sample python script for retrieving the request header is as follows.

  ```
    import time
    import hmac
    from requests import Request

    ts = int(time.time() * 1000)
    request = Request('GET', '<api_endpoint>')
    prepared = request.prepare()
    signature_payload = f'{ts}{prepared.method}{prepared.path_url}'.encode()
    signature = hmac.new('YOUR_API_SECRET'.encode(), signature_payload, 'sha256').hexdigest()

    request.headers['FTX-KEY'] = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
    request.headers['FTX-SIGN'] = signature
    request.headers['FTX-TS'] = str(ts)
  ```

In this case, when your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Unfortunately, `new jsSHA()` cannot be directly used. At Google Apps Script, there is the Class Utilities. You can use the method "computeHmacSha256Signature" of this Class. And, I think that `muteHTTPExceptions: 'true'` is `muteHttpExceptions: true`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"; // Please set your API key.
  var secret = "YOUR_API_SECRET"; // Please set your secret value.

  var host = 'https://ftx.com';
  var endpoint = '/api/wallet/all_balances';
  var url = host + endpoint;
  var timestamp = '' + new Date().getTime();
  var payload = timestamp + 'GET' + endpoint + '';
  var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(payload, secret).map(byte => ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
  var options = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      'FTX-KEY': api_key,
      'FTX-TS': timestamp,
      'FTX-SIGN': signature
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  }
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  console.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

#### References:

- [computeHmacSha256Signature(value, key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computehmacsha256signaturevalue,-key_1)
- [Get balances of all accounts](https://docs.ftx.com/#get-balances-of-all-accounts)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

Comment: @Die Moba Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could understand your question by your provided official document. Thank you, too.